# Jira template alternative in service now

Tags: templates, jira, servicenow

in Jira, you can group a set of tasks as a template, so that you can create them again easily for regular situations.
Is there a similar template in the service-now?
And if so, what is the permissions required?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to say more about your use case. What kind of tasks?

If they are Project Tasks, then ServiceNow supports project templates:
https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/paris-it-business-management/page/product/project-management/concept/c_ProjectTemplates.html

If they are Catalog Tasks, then an administrator would be expected to "script" it in Flow Designer.

If they are Incidents, well, Incidents do not occur in "sets", so the question does not make sense.

Comment: I believe, if you read the question carefully, you will understand.